# Changing a div's id in order to show/hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My old code looked like this:

```
function unhide(rad) {
var id = "answer" + rad.id.replace("-", "");
var answer = document.getElementById(id);
if (answer) {
    var current = document.getElementById(currentShown);
    if (current) current.className = "hidden";
    currentShown = id;
    answer.className = "unhidden";
}
}
```

When my radio button was clicked:

```
<input class="editable" type="radio" name="q1" id="q1-a" onclick="unhide(this); scoreIncrement(this);"/>John
```

It would unhide this div:

```
<div id="answerq1a" class="hidden">
<p>Your answer is correct, John is 6ft2.</p>
</div>
```

But now, my radio button must look like this:

```
<input class="editable" type="radio" name="q1" id="untitled-region-1" onclick="unhide(this); scoreIncrement(this);"/>John
```

and my div that I want to unhide has the same id, but as they are unique, it replaces the 1 with the next number up. In my case it is 4 id's down so the id would be "untitled-region-5" for the new id, as follows:

```
<div id="untitled-region-5" class="hidden">
<p>Your answer is correct, John is 6ft2.</p>
</div>
```

So how can I change this code, to grab the new id "untitled-region-5" and minus 4 from it to fix it to the radio button with the new id's?

```
function unhide(rad) {
var id = "answer" + rad.id.replace("-", "");
var answer = document.getElementById(id);
if (answer) {
    var current = document.getElementById(currentShown);
    if (current) current.className = "hidden";
    currentShown = id;
    answer.className = "unhidden";
}
}
```

I am going along this sort of track:

```
function unhide2(rad) {
var id = $("div").attr('id').replace(/untitled-region-/, 'untitled-region-');
var untitled-region = document.getElementById(id);
if (untitled-region) {
    var current = document.getElementById(currentShown);
    if (current) current.className = "hidden";
    currentShown = id;
    untitled-region.className = "unhidden";
}
}
```

But I don't know how to replace the last digit on the id with "digit-4".

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't just switch between `display: none;` and `display: block;` for this?  That way you don't need to change any ids at all.  Just search for the id of the element you want to show/hide and change the style.

Comment: Because the id's will be created by a CMS which I have no control over. They are giving the id's and what if the id's exceed 20? Then it will not work because I've made my code only up to 20 etc... I need something dynamic that can easily change according to what the CMS does.

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged this with jQuery, so I'll give you the jQuery answer.

The right way to solve this is not to mash about with id's, but to link the radio, and it's associated div some other way, and IMO the best way is using a `data-` attribute.

```
<input class="editable" type="radio" 
   name="q1" id="q1-a" data-answerId="untitled-region-5"/>John
```

Then your javascript becomes easy-as:

```
$('.editable').click(function(){
   $('#' + currentShown).removeClass('unhidden').addClass('hidden');
   var answerId = $(this).data('answerId');
   $('#' + answerId).removeClass('hidden').addClass('unhidden');
});
```

Although I urge you to do away with the `unhidden`, `hidden` confusion and just use `.show()` and `.hide()`!

Comment: Great advice, problem being is that I am allowing someone to edit this through a CMS. I removed my id's which made it work and the CMS put it's own id's in, this is why I have this problem. Putting what you have suggested, which is great, won't work as I can't give people access to the id's in order for them to change them. I was thinking of something like this now: var n = $(this).attr('id').match(/untitled-region-(\d+)/)[1]; and then what? n-4?